# The idea to understand forms.

Tags: calculus

I'm learning forms. In the teacher approach he defines a multi-index $I$ with length $k$ the set $I=\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$, with $1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq N$ and say that we can write the $k$-form $dx_J$ as

1. $$
   dx_J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_1}},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}}\right)=\delta_{IJ}
   $$
   to conclude that such $k$-form are written as
   $$
   w=\sum^{'}_{|J|=k}w_J \, dx_J
   $$
   where the sum signal with ' is the sum over all the multi-index $J$ with length $k$ (i.e. $|J|=k$).Furthermore, he writes 
   $$w_J=w\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_1}},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}} \right)
   $$

**I don't understand why the first equation is true.**

Furthermore, I'm trying to solve that

$$
dx_I\wedge dx_J=(-1)^{pq} \, dx_J\wedge d_I
$$
where $|I|=p$ and $|J|=q$. But I'm confused about how "open" these multi-indices to show that, even suspecting that I show a permutation of $ pq $ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which equation you mean, so I'll take a stab at both:

If $J = (j_1,\dotsc,j_k)$, then what your professor writes as $dx_J$ is a useful shorthand for $dx_{j_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge dx_{j_k}$. Applying this to $\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_1}},\dotsc,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}}\big)$, note that for each $n$ with $1\leq n\leq k$, by definition, $dx_{j_n}\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_n}}\big) = \delta_{i_nj_n}$. Are you able to extend that observation to the whole multi-index?

As for the sum, the idea is that the $dx_J$ form a basis for the space of $k$-forms (you can check this), so *any* $k$-form can be written as a linear combination of basis elements. Using the equation with the $\delta_{IJ}$, then, the last equation follows.